# LEFT and RIGHT JOIN in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I currently have a query which looks like the following

```
SELECT 
    p.*, total
FROM 
    scripts p
LEFT JOIN   
    (SELECT script_id, COUNT(*) as total FROM creator_log WHERE created_date > timestampadd(hour, -6, now()) GROUP BY script_id) p2
ON 
    p.script_id = p2.script_id
WHERE 
    (p2.total < 1 OR p2.total IS NULL) 
AND 
    p.script_status = '1'
ORDER BY 
    p.script_id DESC
LIMIT 
    1
```

How can I then `count()` the `script_id`'s which are found from another table called `products` based on the returned `p.script_id` and then make sure the `count` is less than 5 ?

I assume I'm supposed to do a RIGHT JOIN of some sort?

**EDIT** I tried the following to no avail

```
SELECT 
    p.*, total, active_total
FROM 
    scripts p
LEFT JOIN   
    (SELECT script_id, COUNT(*) as total FROM creator_log WHERE created_date > timestampadd(hour, -6, now()) GROUP BY script_id) p2
ON 
    p.script_id = p2.script_id
RIGHT JOIN  
    (SELECT script_id, COUNT(*) as active_total FROM products WHERE last_used < timestampadd(hour, -6, now()) AND status = 1) p3
ON
    p.script_id = p3.script_id
WHERE 
    (p2.total < 1 OR p2.total IS NULL) 
AND 
    (p3.active_total < 5 or p3.active_total IS NULL)
AND 
    p.script_status = '1'
ORDER BY 
    p.script_id DESC
LIMIT
    1
```

Comment: If you include a table you are outer joining to in your where clause, you have effectively made it an inner join, that's your first problem.  I'd suggest a [SQL tutorial](www.w3schools.com/sql).

Comment: what's wrong? I'm not the best SQL expert known to man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you need to do an inner join or full join (not right or left) like this:

```
SELECT p.*, total
FROM scripts p
LEFT JOIN   
    (SELECT script_id, COUNT(*) as total 
     FROM creator_log 
     WHERE created_date > timestampadd(hour, -6, now()) 
     GROUP BY script_id) p2
   ON p.script_id = p2.script_id AND p2.total < 1
JOIN 
   (SELECT script_id, COUNT(*) as active_total 
    FROM products
    WHERE last_used < timestampadd(hour, -6, now()) AND status = 1) p3
  ON p.script_id = p3.script_id AND p3.active_total < 5
WHERE p.script_status = '1'
ORDER BY p.script_id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Note you can add more than one requirement to the ON clause and thus make your where clause simpler and easier to understand.

How this works:  Because the join on p3 is a full join elements in both scripts and p3 have to exist.  This makes the elements in p3 "required" as you described.

Comment: @Curtis - do you have data that matches the criteria?